# ERROR: No build artifacts found when tried to build my gradle project on jitpack

Tags: gradle, jitpack

I'm getting error when I tried to build and release on JitPack

[My build.gradle.kts](https://github.com/alvin0319/NeisAPI/blob/master/build.gradle.kts)

[Build log](https://jitpack.io/com/github/alvin0319/NeisAPI/-bf53993818-1/build.log)

Build failed with message "ERROR: No build artifacts found".

How can I fix this? Thank you for answer!